# Splitting numbers and letters in string which contains both

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split following (or similar) string "08-27-2015 07:25:00AM".
Currently I use

```
var parts = date.split(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

Which results in

```
["02", "27", "2012", "03", "25", "00AM"]
```

The problem is with the `00AM` part. I want it to be separated too. So the perfect result would be:

```
["02", "27", "2012", "03", "25", "00", "AM"]
```

Comment: Is the format of the input consistently a date in that format?

Comment: Are you interested in splitting or in actual parts of string?

Comment: I am using it indeed to parse dates that way. Sergio, not sure what you mean. I want to get correct parts and I try that by splitting the string.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're looking for sequences of letters or numbers, but not a sequence both mixed, you can do this...

```
"08-27-2015 07:25:00AM".match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g)
```

resulting in...

```
["08", "27", "2015", "07", "25", "00", "AM"]
```

On either side of the `|`, we have a sequence of one or more letters and a sequence of one or more numbers. So when it comes across a letter, it will gather all contiguous letters until it reaches a non-letter, at which point it gathers all contiguous numbers, and so on.

Any other character simply doesn't match so it doesn't become part of the result.

Comment: That's just perfect, it even splits '02June2015'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = "08-27-2015 07:25:00AM";
var parts = date.replace(/([AP]M)$/i, " $1").split(/[^0-9a-z]+/ig);

var date = "05June2012";
var parts = date.replace(/([a-z]+)/i, " $1 ").split(/[^0-9a-z]+/ig);
```

Comment: While you could write a generic splitter, you would need to know what to expect in the resulting array. So I am not sure if it would have any useful purpose as far as parsing is concerned i.e. if you don't know the format of input, the resulting array would be of different size and would have different kind of elements in different locations. How would you know what to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always in that format you can use:

`var parts = date.match(/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(AM|PM)/).splice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a date library to parse the fields you want. That way you can handle multiple formats and not worry about parsing with regular expressions. While [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) is a little old it performs well for parsing.