# Extracting numbers in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, extract

My app reads excel from a user. The app will receive "Quantity and Unit" of an item.

For Example,

5pcs.

12oz.

5lb.

I would like to get the number and store it in var qu[0].
I would like to get the string and store it in var qu[1].

How can i do it? I tried split. but only the number is taken.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: You could use a regexp based split. This is related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742110/splitting-numbers-and-letters-in-string-which-contains-both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number with an regular expression an the following pattern:

```
^(\d*)(.*)$
```

[How to use regular expressions in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(Number("45a".match(/\d*/)) + 1)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zep0tu0b/

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to extract the number.

Then the remaining part should be the unit.

```
var num = parseFloat(str),
    unit = str.substr(num.toString().length);
```

Consider checking if `num` is `NaN`, and then set `unit` to something else.